# Is XNA Development for iOS feasible? is XNATouch the only good XNA implementation for iPhone?

Tags: ios, mono, xna, xamarin.ios

I want to develop and port some of our windows phone 7 games to the iOS platform.
But currently it seems that our only option is: MonoTouch + XNATouch?
Do you use any other SDK for running XNA games on the iOS?
**What is your opinion on developing XNATouch Games?**

http://xnatouch.codeplex.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you run XNA games on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666668/can-you-run-xna-games-on-android)

Comment: only if iOS and Android are the same thing, hence NOT

Comment: They are the same thing as far as they are NOT .NET

Comment: I tried XNATouch and had issues getting the samples to run properly (SIGIOT errors).  I decided it wasn't worth the hassle and started learning Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Andrei :) well on XNATouch Stuff currently they are on 1.0 stable version wich only supports XNA 3.1 and only with spritebatch no 3D available at the moment, in the next releases the will be dropping 3.1 support because you can no longer release games on XBLIG that are built under 3.1 and they will be bringing XNA 4.0 support, when you may ask unfortunately there is no ETA. As this is an open source implementation brought to all of us by a great community its prone to bugs but as a great community we all are you can always submit a bug or fix the code yourself and submit a patch.

The best thing you can do its to give it a chance and try then decide yourself if it fits your needs.

Hope this helps

Alex

Answer (score 2):

You might want to support [ExEn](http://rockethub.com/projects/752-exen-xna-for-iphone-android-and-silverlight), this guys is trying to get support to open source his port to iPhone, Mac and Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can so do this now!  Time has marched on and XNA development is a reality on iOS using [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/).

Here are some app store games written using this framework:

- [Console Wars](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/console-wars/id377179852?mt=8)
- [Chicken Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/chicken-story-plus/id474635095?mt=8)
- [Derfwood](http://itunes.apple.com/app/derfwood/id484106614?mt=8)