# Can you run XNA games on Android?

Tags: android, mono, xna, xamarin.android

I'm searching the internet for a while now, and it seems that currently there is almost no way to develop XNA games for the Android platform. 

Does anyone of you know any good way to port XNA games to the android platform?
XNATouch it doesn't have yet a port for the monodroid, are there any other projects for this?

Comment: For any current readers, I would like to point out that now (September 2011), XNATouch (MonoTouch) has a port for MonoDroid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like you to read the following link, about a project called [ExEn](http://rockethub.com/projects/752-exen-xna-for-iphone-android-and-silverlight) (a port of XNA to several mobile devices)!

Comment: It's on its way at least! Keep an eye out for the future, but today there exist no direct XNA port for Android. You'll have to port it manually. :/

Answer (score 10):

You may also want to consider MonoGame ( https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/ ) as that is also an Open Source, OpenGL implementation of XNA that currently has support for iOS, Android, MacOS X, Windows and recently Linux. It is currently OpenGL ES 1.1, but there is already a team working on ES 2.0 support. Hey now that Sony have embraced C# for their PS Vita and some Xperia phones, maybe the guys at mono will port MonoGame to those platforms and PS3.

Actually ExEn, is a fork of MonoGame( originally called XNATouch ).

For a list of 12 games on the AppStore currently using MonoGame look here - http://monogame.codeplex.com/

I hope this helps.

D.

Answer (score 0):

You would port it much like you would port any software to another platform.

Look at what the original code does, then replicate the end result with the different language, technologies and api's the other platform brings to you.

If what you mean by "Port" is, "Can I run my C# \ XNA code on android with little to no modifications" as of yet no, but as you are aware, there are efforts to make it so.